# Algorithms or OO stuff or new technology

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to learn new stuff about jquery, html, asp .net mvc. I see two school of thoughts -

1. Those who use oo concepts a lot and stress on more object oriented approach
2. Those who rely heavily on algorithms and say a particular problem should take o(n) etc.

I am not sure where to spend more time ? . Should I spend more time learning OO stuff or learn new stuff like jquery etc or learn travelling sales man algorithm etc ?

Comment: This should be Community Wiki as there's no objective right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1 is software engineering, aka secrets of the trade. Number 2 is computer science, aka theory. Both are important, but it's much easier to pick up the former on the job. If you have time to exclusively dedicate to study (rather than read a blog post or an article here and there), I'd go with algorithms over libraries and practices any day.

Comment: +1. Algorithms and other theory you will not be able to pick up later as you go. It takes abstract study. Unlike OO and general design practices.

Comment: Huh? Both areas you mention (software engineering and computer science) make use of both things the question mentions (OO and algorithms). Are you trying to say that software engineering = OO and computer science = algorithms?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Technically you are correct, but the application of object-oriented techniques (among others) is definitely in the domain software engineering much more than it is in the domain of computer science. Algorithms (especially the more complex ones) are *used* in SE, but *studied* in CS.